# Inverse of a function $e^x + 2e^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The function is $f(x) = e^x+2e^{2x}$

So to find the inverse I went

$$WTS: x = ____$$

$$y =  e^x+2e^{2x}$$

$$ log3(y)=log3(3e^{2x})$$
$$ log3(y) = 2x$$
$$ log3(y)=5x$$
$$ x=\frac{log3(y)}{2}$$

Am i correct?

Comment: plug in $x=f^{-1}(y)$ into the original equation, what do you get?

Comment: $\log(a+2b)\ne \log(a)+2\log(b)$.

Comment: Set $Z = e^x$ and note $f(x) = Z + 2Z^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Continue Daniel's suggestion: set $e^x=t$ and solve for $t$
$$
2t^2+t-y=0
$$
the second root is obviously negative, so it doesn't work, , hence your solution is 
$$
t=\frac{\sqrt{1+8y}-1}{4}
$$
and hence 
$$
x=\log \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1+8y}-1}{4}\bigg)
$$
Plug it in the original equation and see what you get

Answer (score 1):

No, you are wrong, $log$ is not a linear function,  set $g(x)=e^x$, $2g(x)^2+g(x)-y=0$，
solving this equation, since $y>0$, $g(x)=e^x=-{1\over4}+{1\over 2}\sqrt{{1\over4}+2y}.$